# How to validate the format of a collection DateTime(s) in a json input?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I know how to validate a DateTime of a specific format using an annotation.
I know how to validate a collection of DateTime (ensure they are all valid).

I can't find how to validate that in an inputed json, all DateTimes in a collection are of a specific format.

I need to validate that in a `IList` of `DateTime`, all dates match the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

I tried a custom class attribute with an overriden `IsValid` function.

Does not work, because I receive an object which is already an `Enumerable<DateTime>` with DateTimes already converted for the inputed json strings.

The json input `"DatesList": ["2012-10-01", "2012-10"]` should not be valid, but `"2012-10"` has already been converted to a DateTime with value `2012-10-01` when I get to check if the format is correct (in the IsValid function).

Here is my target class for json deserialization when I need my reusable attribute to be used for checking that all the inputed dates in the json are valid.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace XXX
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles a Forex Rate and its history
    /// </summary>
    public class FxRate : IExamplesProvider
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Base currency of the Forex Rate
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]{3}$", ErrorMessage = "bla")]
        public string BaseCurrency { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Target currency of the Forex Rate
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]{3}$", ErrorMessage = "bla")]
        public string TargetCurrency { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// List of dates 
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [EnsureValidHistoryDates]
        public IList<DateTime> Dates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then my attempt of an attribute function :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class EnsureValidHistoryDatesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = Format };

        IEnumerable<object> values = value as IEnumerable<object>;

        // problem here, values is always null

        if (values != null)
        {
            foreach (var val in values)
            {
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(val as string, dateTimeConverter);

                if (obj == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        var casted = value as IEnumerable<DateTime>;
        if (casted != null)
        {
            var distCount = casted.Distinct().Count();
            var count = casted.Count();
            return count == distCount;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Format error message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">name of the field</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(Resources.InvalidHistoryDates, name);
    }
}
```

Any generic method to validate, with an attribute annotation, a collection of type with a specific format on T would be so welcome, because I am stuck here (and I tried a lot of different searches on google).

Answer (score 2):

```
List<DateTime> validDates = new List<DateTime>();
List<DateTime> invalidDates = new List<DateTime>();

List<string> dateTimes = new List<string>() {
    "20181227",
    "2018-12-27",
    "27/12/2018",
    "12/27/2018"
}; //INSTEAD OF DECLARING THE DATES, THERE SHOULD BE THE CONVERSION FROM JSON TO STRINGS LIST    

foreach(string dateTime in dateTimes)
{
    bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result);

    if (isValid)
    {
        validDates.Add(result);
    }
    else
    {
        invalidDates.Add(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: "validate that in a IList of DateTime, all dates match the format "yyyy-MM-dd".??? (Consider clarifying what you actually answering)

Comment: Yes that's what this code does, then the OP knows what to do with the result

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I understand that I was not clear enough in my request / way to describe my problem.
I know how to validate a date or a collection of dates, I want a generic method to do it by attribute on json inputs. I'll try to edit my original post.